# jquery error "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

This jQuery code is part of a simple thumbnail gallery.  It is loaded into a fancybox when I click a link on a page.  When I added a preloader part, everything looks ok, but I get an error in firebug: `$(imgSwap).preload` is not a function.

I'm not sure what I am missing or is that it is getting loaded through ajax into the fancy?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Image swap on hover
    $("#gallery li img").hover(function(){
        $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    });
    // Image preload
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#gallery li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src;
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}   
</script>


    <div id="gallery">
        <img src="http://photos2.img.ie/Full-10176257.jpeg" alt="" id="main-img" width="290px" height="200px"/>
        <ul>
          <li><img src="http://photos2.img.ie/Full-10176257.jpeg" alt="" width="69px" height="52" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://photos2.img.ie/Full-10176258.jpeg" alt="" width="69px" height="52" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://photos2.img.ie/Full-10176259.jpeg" alt="" width="69px" height="52" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://photos2.img.ie/Full-10176260.jpeg" alt="" width="69px" height="52" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://photos2.img.ie/Full-10176262.jpeg" alt="" width="69px" height="52" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://photos2.img.ie/Full-10176256.jpeg" alt="" width="69px" height="52" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try declaring your `preload()` method *before* you call it.

Comment: You cannot create a jQuery object from an array of arbitrary strings, or at least you should not.

Comment: Hi Felix I am still learning so I do not have best practice. Could you point me to the way I should? What line exactly,  to me they are all arrays, so I am missing something important. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you are calling your preload function before its declaration, try declaring that function at the top of your code then give call to preload function.

Answer (score 2):

`$(document).ready` calls the callback when the DOM is ready. Alternatively, if the DOM is already ready, it calls it straight away.  This is clearly so in this case.

For safety, define your jQuery methods (here `$.fn.preload`) before you use them.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I tried moving things around as suggested but I am not a 100% sure what you mean. Could you supply move detail? I have a $(document).ready in the main page the above code gets loaded with the ajax.